# Passing list values to class with tkinter button

Tags: python, list, button, lambda, tkinter

I am trying multiple instances names from a list to a class when pressing a button where I want to perform multiple mathematical equations at the same time with the values entered from the users in the entry fields.

For example: aud_non_comm_short / aud_non_comm_long & cad_non_comm_short / cad_non_comm_long and display results for both in labels.

I have a problem with passing the values with the lambda via the button:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class CoTValues:

    def non_comm_short(self, master, e_row):
        self.master = master
        self.e_row = e_row
        self.non_comm_short = IntVar()
        entry = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.non_comm_short, width="9")
        entry.grid(row=self.e_row, column="1", padx="5", pady="5")

    def non_comm_long(self, master, e_row):
        self.master = master
        self.e_row = e_row
        self.non_comm_long = IntVar()
        entry = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.non_comm_long, width="9")
        entry.grid(row=self.e_row, column="2", padx="5", pady="5")

    def display_data(self):
        print(self.non_comm_short.get())
        print(self.non_comm_long.get())

root = Tk()
root.minsize(width="500", height="500")

aud_non_comm_short = CoTValues()
aud_non_comm_short.non_comm_short(root, 1)

aud_non_comm_long = CoTValues()
aud_non_comm_long.non_comm_long(root, 1)

cad_non_comm_short = CoTValues()
cad_non_comm_short.non_comm_short(root, 2)

cad_non_comm_long = CoTValues()
cad_non_comm_long.non_comm_long(root, 2)

var_name = [aud_non_comm_short, aud_non_comm_long]

btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=lambda: for x in range(len(var_name): var_name[x].display_data())
btn.grid(row="4", column="3")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you using `lambda` in this case? Why not call just a normal function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up the naming of your variables and functions, since you named them the same. The lambda button call did not work for me so I changed the function. This does the job but it is a dirty solution. So you can simply improve it.

```
    from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class CoTValues:

    def define_non_comm_short(self, master, e_row):
        self.master = master
        self.e_row = e_row

        self.non_comm_short = IntVar()
        self.entry = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.non_comm_short, width="9")
        self.entry.grid(row=self.e_row, column="1", padx="5", pady="5")

    def define_non_comm_long(self, master, e_row):

        self.master = master
        self.e_row = e_row

        self.non_comm_long = IntVar()
        self.entry = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.non_comm_long, width="9")
        self.entry.grid(row=self.e_row, column="2", padx="5", pady="5")

    def display_data(self, var_name):
        for v in var_name:
            print('')
            print(v.entry.get())
        print("-------------")

#--------------------------
def button_func(var_name):
    aud_non_comm_short.display_data(var_name)

#---------- main ----------
root = Tk()
root.minsize(width="500", height="500")

aud_non_comm_short = CoTValues()
aud_non_comm_short.define_non_comm_short(root, 1)

aud_non_comm_long = CoTValues()
aud_non_comm_long.define_non_comm_long(root, 1)

cad_non_comm_short = CoTValues()
cad_non_comm_short.define_non_comm_short(root, 2)

cad_non_comm_long = CoTValues()
cad_non_comm_long.define_non_comm_long(root, 2)

var_name = [aud_non_comm_short, aud_non_comm_long]

btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Submit", command= lambda: button_func(var_name))
btn.grid(row="4", column="3")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kogito this solved my problem you guys are awesome!!